# Additional structure on random effects model (flip sign of estimate according to pre-defined structure)

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I am exploring the estimation of a random effects model with a slightly atypical structure. Specifically, I have a dataset of observations which each include 2 individuals, lets say party A and party B.

A number of individuals feature multiple times across the database, sometimes as party A and sometimes as party B (albeit never both in the same observation). I would like to model random intercepts by individuals, but would like the sign of the intercept to switch dependent on whether some individual is party A or B. So, if some individual features in 100 observations, 50 times as party A and 50 times as party B, I would like the random effect to be identical across all 100 observations, but the sign to be flipped for those observations when the individuals is party A relative to party B.

Does anyone have any experience with a similar setup? I suppose the R lme4 syntax would look something like:

```r
glmer(outcome ~ controls + (1 | A) + (1 | B), structure_var_matrix)
```

Where the structure_var_matrix would be a way to equate estimates between certain groups in A and B, albeit with a flipped sign.

Comment: Linear mixed model: $Y=X\beta +Z\gamma +\epsilon$. $\gamma \sim N(0,\Sigma_1)$, $\epsilon \sim N(0,\Sigma_2)$. Where does your question come from?

Comment: I am looking at a binary outcome mixed model with in fact two random effects. I have my standard regressors X and not one but two non-nested levels. So in effect my specification looks as follows: $Y = X \beta + \eta_j + \theta_k + \epsilon.$ With $\epsilon, \theta, \eta$ all normally distributed. $j$ and $k$ are determined by the fact that each of my observations includes two parties (A and B). The complexity is that some individuals in A also appear in B, so I want their random effect to be identical but with a flipped sign. (Party A and B have reverse effects).

Comment: In your R code, what is variable controls?

Comment: They are just a host of regressors, but for argument's sake they could just be an intercept..

Comment: What do your data look like? Based on "each include 2 individuals, lets say party A and party B" I do not think you can fit the model you wanted.

Comment: Its a little complicated data, but the easiest similar example would be predicting the score of a football match by an outcome which is coded 1 for a win by the home side and a 0 otherwise. Now in addition to standard match-level regressors I would like to fit a random effect for the various teams, but I would like the random effect to be a certain size in case the team is at home and the same size in the reversed case but negative. In other words - I am estimating two random effects, and they have some additional structure imposed on them, namely that the sign of the effect swaps.